# Element randomly positions incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got large amounts of styling going on with javascript (yes, I'm aware it needs to degrade gracefully) and there is one particular element that -randomly- doesn't position correctly.  The line that changes its left margin property seems to be skipped.  So, I used a while loop to make sure it was changing and if not change it.  Now the rate of occurrence is drastically reduced, but still not eliminated!  Is this a known issue with javascript?  The entire chunk of code preceding/succeeding this part isn't more than 30 lines!

```
while (sloganCheck != 1) {
    if ($('#homepage_homestrip_slogan').css('margin-left') != (browserWidth-$('#homepage_homestrip_slogan').width())/2) {
        $('#homepage_homestrip_slogan').css('margin-left',(browserWidth-$('#homepage_homestrip_slogan').width())/2);
        sloganCheck = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this is a ready function, and can we see how you declare `browserWidth`

Comment: I'd be careful about using a loop like that - given that you say the code doesn't set the position correctly in some instances you might end up with an endless loop...

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: sorry about that.  It's just $(window).width()

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yeah, that's what I was half expecting when I did it, but it hasn't happened thus far.